# Div fit according image width

Tags: css, responsive-design, image, inheritance

I have a portfolio page with a image display with zoom.
I have this code: http://codepen.io/Mpleandro/pen/LvrqJ

The div that shows the image has a class of `.display`, on line 13 of the HTML and the css formating for this div isline 90.

The image width will be flexible, so I what I want is to make the containing div inherit the width of image.

I tried the css property `auto`, `inherit` and `min-with`, but nothing works!

Could someone help me?

P.S.: I need a responsive solution.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, your pen is kind of useless without proprer src links to your images . http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HpymJ

Answer (score 7):

since 1 year has passed you may not be interested in the solution, but hope that helps someone else.

I also had a situation like that where I needed a div to be of the same width as the image and this had to be responsive.

In my case, I set a fixed width for the div

```
.some-div{
   width: 250px;
}
```

I also had responsive image:

```
img{
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   height; auto;
}
```

and then I added a media query with threshold when the fixed width of the `div` started to affect the responsive nature and simply addedd this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 917px){
    .some-div{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

For my project the threshold was `917px` when the fixed width started to affect.

I guess it is a solution that will fit everyone since `width: 100%` after the certain threshold will always be the width of the image if the image is responsive.

Comment: @user3127499 why would you care about the bounty? :-) I offered it so as the point would get enough attention.

Comment: just a joke turns out its  not so funny

Comment: @scumah What are you talking about. It is not reddit.

Comment: @scumah @-knitevision- chill guys

Comment: Is this a joke right? Am I being blamed for creating a bounty to get myself some 40 reputation? Is this for real?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to give you a perfect answer, but I can hopefully send you in the right direction. First, you can forget about `inherit` or `min-width` because they are not what you want.

`auto` is the default value, and I think that the default behaviour is very close to what you want: the width of the div adapt to its content. If this is not the current behaviour, this is because of many other reasons including the positioning of that div. The thing is, you won't have a proper centering and sizing of the `<div class="display">` with only CSS, because it would need a specific explicit width declaration.

Since you already use Javascript to display/hide the good images, you could use Javascript to set the width everytime you change the image that is in the box.

My best advice would be to use existing solutions which are tested, approved and look really good. A 2 seconds Google search pointed me to [Fesco](http://www.frescojs.com/) which you could try.

Comment: Fresco isn't working in my mobile. I don't know why, but not the examples in the their own webpage not working. I found another excellent plugin called Shadowbox (www.shadowbox-js.com) It's easy to configure, responsive and with a lot of options. Worth it to check!

Comment: You might want to answer to your own question, then, with a link to [ShadowBox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com), to allow people to find it quickly in the future! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but if it is, I hope it will help!

If you want your image to fill the div, but to scale with the browser, try setting the width of your div. Next, apply `max-width="100%"; height: auto;` to your image.

Comment: Isn't it. I want my div fit according my image size.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to just set `.display` to `display: inline-block;`, which would adjust its size to the contained image. If you want to be responsive as well, you need to define an upper limit via `max-height: 80%`, for example.

Put together, it would look like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IluBt

JS line 17:

```
$(".display").css("display","inline-block");
```

CSS for `.display`

```
.display {
    position: relative;;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    max-height:80%; /* <-- limit the height */
    top:10%;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

And to align everything nicely:

```
.loader {
    color: red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 1) url(../http://www.mpleandro.com.br/images/new/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    text-align: center;
}
```